# Avoiding people to refresh page?

Tags: php, html

i have some problem, i create a page to read news and if the page open it will be update in my database field for news_read +1 but i want if page refresh by user isn't +1

this is my query in page

```
$q="SELECT*FROM t_news WHERE news_id=$b_id";
    $dataJ=mysql_query($q);
    $a=mysql_fetch_array($dataJ);
    $plus=$a['news_read']+1;
mysql_query("UPDATE t_news set news_read=$plus WHERE news_id=$a[news_id]");
```

anyone know, how to disable `$plus=$a['berita_dibaca']+1;` after refreshing the page?

UPDATE

UPDATE

thanks all ,i have solved my problem with session

i put

```
if ($_SESSION['load']==1){
        $_SESSION['load']=0;
    }
```

in all of my page except read.php and i put

```
if ($_SESSION['load']==0)
    {
        //QUERY
    } 
    $_SESSION['load'] = 1;
```

in read.php

Comment: run the update is the referer is not the current page

Answer (score 1):

Method 1.
Save cookie, if user has cookie don't update database.

Method 2. (better)
Save users who have already viewed this article, and if user is in list do not update database.

Tip:

```
UPDATE t_news set news_read = news_read + 1 WHERE news_id = $a[news_id]
```

to avoid useless queries.

Comment: i dont use cookie in my website

Comment: and what if it is an anonymous user?

Comment: Well you can always try to use libraries to detect returning visitors (using cached images, sessions, cookies, browser + ip matching and so on)

Answer (score 0):

That's not a question to solve with sql, but with HTTP.

There is basically no difference between a refresh of a page and the inital request. There both just HTTP commands. There may be a difference in the headers of both requests but you can't always be sure they are present. So using the referer is probaly not a great idea.

Beside Valdas answer with the cookie you may also use the session of your user and set a flag there. (Although most session implementations do also use cookies, but in another way)

Answer (score 0):

This method doesn't require a user to be logged in:

```
session_start(); // ignore if you're already using sessions
if( !isset($_SESSION['has_read_news'])) $_SESSION['has_read_news'] = array();
if( !isset($_SESSION['has_read_news'][$b_id])) {
    mysql_query("UPDATE `t_news` SET `news_read`=`news_read`+1 WHERE `news_id`=".$b_id);
    $_SESSION['has_read_news'][$b_id] = true;
}
```

Note that it's not completely foolproof (clearing the session cookie will allow the user to be counted again) but overall it should be plenty good enough.